# Probability of particle overcoming an energy barrier

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm reading this article called:An experiment to demonstrate the canonical distribution(by M. D. Sturge and Song Bac Toha)
Department of Physics, Dartmouth College, Hanover, New Hampshire 03755.

They talked about the probability of a particle overcoming and energy barrier of height $\Delta E$, they say is proportional to $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(\epsilon)e^{-(\epsilon+\Delta E)/kT}d\epsilon$

I have 2 questions:

-Where does this come from, why would integrating that result in a probability, wouldn't I obtain the total number of particles.

-what factor must I include in order for this to be an equality , that is$ P(\Delta E)= factor \int_{0}^{\infty}g(\epsilon)e^{-(\epsilon+\Delta E)/kT}d\epsilon$

Comment: What is the definition of $g(\epsilon)$?

Comment: In physics same letters may be used to denote different quantities, and formulas may ahve different meaning depending on the context. This is to say that the question does not explain the origin of the formula and understanding it requires some guesswork.

Comment: maybe this will help :  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html .$Ψ^*Ψ$  integrates to 1,

Comment: $g(\epsilon)$ is the density of states

Answer (score 1):

According to Boltzman distribution, the probability of finding the particle in a energy $E$ is propotion to $exp(-\frac{E}{KT})$. Consider a degeneracy for energy $E$ is $g(E)$ the density of states, which means that there are $g(E) dE$ independent levels have their energy in between $E$  and $E+dE$, the resultant probability of finding a particle in one of these energy levels is:

$$
    p(E)dE \propto g(E) dE e^{-\frac{E}{KT}}
$$

Now, there is a energy valley with a barrier $\Delta E$. For particle being able to cross the barrier, the particle must have energy greater that $\Delta E$. The total probability of such particle ($E > \Delta E$):

$$
  p(>\Delta E) \propto \int_{\Delta E}^\infty g(\epsilon) d\epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{KT}}
=\int_{0}^\infty g(\epsilon+\Delta E) d\epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon + \Delta E}{KT}}
$$

(In your expression, the variable inside the density of states $g$ is not correct.)

To make it an equal sign:

$$ 
p(>\Delta E) = \frac{1}{N} \int_{0}^\infty g(\epsilon+\Delta E) d\epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon + \Delta E}{KT}} 
$$

The normalization constant:

$$ 
  N =  \int_0^\infty g(\epsilon) d\epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{KT}} 
$$

Comment: This makes so much sense now, thank you!